# how to add command in nl80211 interface

Tags: sockets, netlink

I want to add a new command in nl80211 interface. i browsed but didnt get information in much details. As far as i know, for adding command we need to add command in **enum nl80211_commands** present in */usr/include/linux/nl80211.h* file line 515, and we need to register a callback function for that command that is done by adding callback function in 
**const struct wpa_driver_ops wpa_driver_nl80211_ops** present in *src/drivers/driver_nl80211.c* after doing all this how to send commands to kernel side i am not getting that part, if anybody knows please help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can modify wpa_supplicant to do it.